# Firebase RemoteConfigSettings doesn't reflect minimumFetchInterval changes

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to change the `minimumFetchInterval` for my `RemoteConfigSettings`. I set the value to 0 but the value doesn't update. As a workaround, I can create a new `RemoteConfigSettings` object, set the value there, and assign the settings to the `remoteConfig` instance.

```
let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
remoteConfig.configSettings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
```

Reading back `minimumFetchInterval` still shows the default of 43200.

The header is defined in Obj-C as:
`@property(nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval minimumFetchInterval;`
So I would expect the value to reflect assignments.

This does work:

```
remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()

let configSettings = RemoteConfigSettings()
configSettings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
remoteConfig.configSettings = configSettings
```

I am able to work around this issue, but this should be fixed. Am I missing something, or should I continue to expect these APIs to be incorrect?

The documentation of the `RemoteConfigSettings` class doesn't even mention the `minimumFetchInterval` property, but their how to docs do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android#throttling), Firebase remote config minimum fetch interval depends on 3 parameters:

1. parameter passed in fetch(long seconds) call.
2. The parameter in FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(long seconds)
3. Default value of 43200 seconds which is 12 hours.

When using `FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(long seconds)`

you need to do it using "**Builder**" pattern & set it in FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings as

**get() operation on FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings does not return the original object being used by the SDK**.

Also, you can see the same in sample project provided by Firebase team [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/config/ConfigExampleSwift/ViewController.swift). i.e.

```
let settings = RemoteConfigSettings()
settings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
remoteConfig.configSettings = settings
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out their sample use. It does say "to enable developer mode", which is a deprecated feature which that sample doesn't use, so I still don't trust their code. Either way, if this is true, then they should make the constructor take the parameter and not have it assign.